# Why are the first two arguments of cgi.FieldStorage None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

In a Python CGI environment, I used the following code to print values from a GET/POST request:

```
import cgi
print(cgi.FieldStorage())
```

The output is:

```
FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('name', 'john')])
```

Here, I supplied the `name` parameter with a value of `'john'`, and I got it as expected.

But why are the first two values `None`?  What are they used for, and what do they hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source of the `cgi.py` module, the [`FieldStorage.__repr__`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/cgi.py#l575) method is:

```
def __repr__(self):
    """Return a printable representation."""
    return "FieldStorage(%r, %r, %r)" % (
            self.name, self.filename, self.value)
```

Both `name` and `filename` are optional values.  For `FieldStorage`, the are set automatically from the `content-disposition` header, if any.

`name` seems to be used as the key for this `FieldStorage` when using the `dict`-style methods like `keys` and `__getitem__`.

`filename` is used by CGI scripts that accept file uploads.

If you get a `MiniFieldStorage` ("for use when no file uploads are possible"), it's [`__repr__`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/cgi.py#l357) is just:

```
def __repr__(self):
    """Return printable representation."""
    return "MiniFieldStorage(%r, %r)" % (self.name, self.value)
```

Same as above, minus the `filename` field.  Unlike `FieldStorage`, it takes the value of `name` in `__init__` and does nothing with it except repeat it in `__repr__`.  (It's probably also used as a dictionary key... somewhere.)

The doc-strings for these two classes are, frankly, much better than what you can find in the [`cgi` module's official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html).  (Also, the `FieldStorage` class does a *lot* of different things, making it hard to describe in words.)